# Warning: 'sandbox' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium

Tags: visual-studio-code, electron

I am using `Linux Mint 20` and `vscode 1.52.1`.

My `~/.xsession-errors` file shows `Warning: 'sandbox' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium.`

What is causing this error and what is the solution to it?

Comment: this is when you run your app, or when you run vscode (which is built on top of electron)

Comment: @pushkin why is it considered a warning?

Comment: Happens on Void linux too, except 'Warning: 'app' is not...' output direct to console: `code --version` gives `1.52.1`, `electron9 --version` gives `v9.3.4`.

Comment: Seen on Ubuntu 21.04 too. The warning is produced while opening a file in VSCode.

Comment: I started getting this warning today. CONFIG: 

```sh
Version: 1.58.0 | 
Commit: 2d23c42a936db1c7b3b06f918cde29561cc47cd6 | 
Date: 2021-07-08T06:53:55.113Z | 
Electron: 12.0.13 | 
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128 | 
Node.js: 14.16.0 | 
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0 | 
OS: Linux x64 5.8.0-59-generic snap | 
```

Comment: This is the first time I see this warning when opening vscode from terminal

Comment: Seen on Ubuntu 20.04 too, when opening a file in VSCode, just like @peter.slizik said.

Comment: Its mostly with vs code version 1.58.0  June 2021 release

Comment: There is currently a [ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128279) on github.com for this issue. It is with the new release!

Comment: I see this warning since 1.58.0 on Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I removed the snap version and install the deb file which works for me

```
sudo snap remove code
```

Downlaod `code_1.58.1-1626158276_amd64.deb` (latest) file from https://code.visualstudio.com/download

and install it with --fix-broken option

```
cd ~/Downloads/ && sudo apt --fix-broken install ./code_1.58.1-1626158276_amd64.deb
```