# Warning: 'sandbox' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium. ubuntu 20.04

Tags: visual-studio-code

Warning when I open VSCode from terminal in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

```
"Warning: 'sandbox' is not in the list of known options, but still passed to Electron/Chromium."
```

Comment: This is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65441950/warning-sandbox-is-not-in-the-list-of-known-options-but-still-passed-to-elec